# Two token security: JWT/Oauth2 in regular cookie plus OAuth2 refresh token in HttpOnly cookie?

Tags: javascript, security, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, jwt

I'm exploring JWT and OAuth2 for a Javascript Single-Page-App which will make calls to a backend server-side API. I've come up with a security process that involves using two tokens and gives me the advantage of avoiding the need to have an additional server-side session storage:

1. The first time the client JS app is loaded up, user sends username/password **over SSL** to OAuth2 server. The server will set a cookie (normal cookie that is readable by client, without any HttpOnly flag set) that contains a JWT with an OAuth2 access token inside it's claims (along with some other non-confidential data in the JWT claims, ie. user's first/last name, country, role/permission). The server will also set a HttpOnly cookie that will contain the OAuth2 refresh token.
2. The cookies set by the server will be included on every request from the client automatically (always over SSL), so the server will receive the JWT (see step 3) and both confirm the signature and confirm the OAuth2 access token. The server will also confirm the refresh token. Since the server is checking the access token and refresh token against the OAuth2 database on each request, this gives us the ability to revoke access (which we would not be able to do with the JWT signature alone). We can do a "hard" revoke which revokes both access and refresh token. And we can do a "soft" revoke which just revokes the access token (for instances where perhaps some data that we keep in the JWT claim gets updated, ie. user changes their name or country or role). A soft revoke would be invisible to the client end user (it wouldn't disrupt their logged in status).
3. In step 2 above, the server will **actually** look for the JWT in a specific header set by the client (instead of the cookie set by the server). For example, the client JS app will read the JWT from the cookie and then set the JWT in another part of the header. By requring the client to explicitly set a header key/value containing the JWT shows that the client was able to read it's own cookie, thus preventing against XSRF (cross-site request forgery).
4. The HttpOnly cookie that contains the refresh token ensures we are protected against XSS (ie. some malicious javascript that sneaked its way onto our client). If our JWT was stolen, access still wouldn't be granted because the refresh token was not also seen or stolen by the JS.

With this approach we get all these benefits:

- **We don't need a server-side session storage**. Since we are hitting an OAuth2 server then we can simply just include some extra data in the JWT that we return (non-confidential data). We wouldn't need to re-query/refresh the data in the JWT every time, but perhaps only when the OAuth token is revoked (ie. was revoked when some user data was changed that we include in the JWT's). No need to tackle the storage/scaling requirement that comes with using sessions. The client JS app can use this data like any other app would normally use sessions. For instance I can display a user's name on every "page" in the app. We could also just use websockets, but the JWT is a good backup place for adding some data if we need it.
- **We are protected against XSRF**.
- **We are protected against XSS.**
- **We can revoke access and also log users out** (which is not easily possible with JWT alone).
- **SSL** prevents man-in-the-middle attacks.
- **The JWT adds a little extra security hurdle for attackers to pass versus just a normal JSON object serialized in the cookie.** The attacker would need to get the server-side key for signing JWT's (in addition to OAuth access). The JWT is also a standard, so easier for a trusted developer to work with.
- **The JWT can be easily passed down to other micro-services sitting behind the OAuth layer to use service-to-service**. We can pass it around as "session like" data access to all the services on a request. If a service want's to change something in that data, then they can inform OAuth2 server and it will "soft" revoke the user's current JWT (not really much different from the process with a session storage) and provide a new one.

I haven't exactly seen anyone detail a security process like this yet. Many I see seem to only talk about using JWT with an OAuth2 access token inside and don't elaborate much more. **So my question is, does this approach indeed provide the benefits I listed above? If not, what am I missing here and what security hole have I not covered for?**

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on [security.se], which specializes in security issues.

Comment: refresh tokens can be quite large, so sending refresh + access tokens on each and every request could be considered expensive for some applications. 

What about storing the access token in memory and setting the refresh token to a fixed path ("/login")? That way CSRF is quite limited attack surface and an XSS attack would have additional hurdle of reading access token from your code. Downside to this is any time user refreshes page you would need to continually first retrieve access token using refresh token, since there's no persistence of it.